# Can I load a blend file and execute a script with the blend file with Blender in the background

Tags: scripting, command-line

I would like Blender to perform a task in the background.  In order to do the task, I need to have a blend file loaded and run a script (or an operator).  I've tried the following batch file (with the full pathname of my blend file and my script):

```
echo on
cd "c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.3"

:: Blend files are opened and new data saved in the following script
.\blender -b "full path of blend file" -P "full path of python script"
```

and the following script:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile(app_template='Application_Template')
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=r"full path of blend file")
bpy.ops.myops.update()
```

I managed to get this to work by opening the blend file in the script instead of the batch file.  It looks to me that the command line Blender opens the blend file and then it runs the script without the blend file.

Is there a way I can run a script or operator (from my addon) with a blend file and Blender in the background?  I thought that it would be easier to apply the Python script to a list of blend files if I can have both in Blender's command line.

Comment: The order of arguments can break things, that could be the case here. `-b` should be first. `blender -b "blend file path" -P "script file path"`.

Comment: Putting -b before the blend file path does not help.  It still opens the blend file, and then runs the script without the blend file.  If I remove the script and try to use the load handler, the load handler of my addon does not run.  I tried putting the Python commands in the if __name__ == "__main__": section of my addon and it still did not run.

Comment: Share your script here, so that we can check by ourselves.